# Erratic scrollwheel behavior - scrolling moves page randomly top or down

Tags: usb, 16.04, mouse, scrolling

While scrolling using my wireless mouse, the behavior seems erratic. Sometimes while scrolling down, the page will scroll up and vice versa. The behavior intensifies if I scroll faster, and seems to happen more often when I stop scrolling (e.g I scroll down, the page scrolls down and then jumps up when I stop scrolling).

The model is LOGITECH MK270 and it's brand new.

Furthermore, after substituting the faulty mouse with an other on my linux machine, the substitute mouse scrolls perfectly. However, after connecting my faulty wireless mouse to a windows 10 machine, it scrolls fine - I can only conclude the mouse itself works fine and it's most probably a driver issue.

Any helpful advice is appreciated.

Comment: How old is this mouse?

Comment: It's brand new, it came as a combo with a keyboard, the model is logitech  MK270

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me also. Furthermore, there were some logs in /var/log/syslog showing some ACPI errors:

```
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425512] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000044F (\GPIS) (20150930/utaddress-254)
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425521] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425527] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425531] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\GPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425537] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GP01) (20150930/utaddress-254)
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425542] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
Jan 22 09:04:06 nb-S500CA kernel: [    6.425543] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000057F (\GPIO) (20150930/utaddress-254)
```

But then I have noticed, that the wheel is not balanced. There are positions, where it moves by itself to balanced position. But then I have noticed, that there is switch on the mouse - which allows me to switch between "free movement" and "discrete movement" - and it helped.